# Custom Formatter does not allow to move focus on the other text field

Tags: macos, cocoa

Below is the code of PasswordFormatter which does not allow whitespaces and maximum length is 15. When input string and they try to click on other text field it does not move, the cursor stays on same password field.

```
import Cocoa

class PasswordFormatter: Formatter {
    var maxLength:Int = 15
    override func string(for obj: Any?) -> String? {
        if obj is String{
            return obj as? String
        }
        else
        {
            return nil
        }
    }


override func getObjectValue(_ obj: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>?, for string: String, errorDescription error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>?) -> Bool {
    print("string is...\(string)")
    obj?.pointee = string as AnyObject
    return false
}

override func editingString(for obj: Any) -> String? {
    if obj is String{
        return obj as? String
    }
    else
    {
        return nil
    }
}



override func isPartialStringValid(_ partialString: String, newEditingString newString: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>?, errorDescription error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>?) -> Bool {

    if partialString.characters.count > maxLength
    {
        return false;
    }


    if partialString.rangeOfCharacter(from: NSCharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines) != nil
    {
        return false
    }

    // Ability to reset your field (otherwise you can't delete the content)
    // You can check if the field is empty later
    if partialString.isEmpty {
        return true
    }

    // Actual check
    return true
}
}
```

Not sure what the exact problem while using custom formatter.

Comment: Why are you returning `false` from `getObjectValue...`?

Comment: See here the implementation  - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/formatter/1408927-getobjectvalue, if no error then return false. in my case it should allow all any input. If return true, anything you type in textfield will not be shown in textfield. Returns true means avoid input , return false means accept input.

Comment: *if no error then return false* - it doesn't say this anywhere on the page you linked; rather, it says *[return] true if the conversion from string to cell content object was successful, otherwise false*. Have you tried returning `true` instead of `false`? I have, and it behaves as I think you want it to behave.